# Setup FakeRaid Raid1 for data only for Ubuntu 14.10 and Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, raid, mdadm, dmraid

I want to create a FakeRaid RAID1 array of two hdd's that are being used only for data, no OS's on them. My OS's are Ubuntu 14.10 and Windows 7 which are each on seperate hdd's. Almost all of the guides out there cover installing OS's but I dont want to do that.

I have data on one of them that would be nice to keep but I have a backup if that's not possible.

Since its for Windows and Ubuntu I would like to leave it as NTFS which both dirvers currently are in.

My Motherboard in Gigabyte MA790XT-UD4P which supports RAID

How do I set up the RAID1?

Comment: And your question is???  How to set up the RAID1?  Which file system to use? If the former: Does your BIOS support RAIDing? If the latter: What do you want to do?  :/  Please [edit] your question and try to be more clear.  (or blame it on me: I'm naturally confused!)  ;-)